# Length of an Access Binary field

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm using OleDB in a .Net app to read an Access Database table which has a Binary field of fixed length. When I use the `MaxLength` property on the `DataTable` it returns -1, although in the Access DB itself I can see the length of the field is 510 bytes. I can't see the field length anywhere - can you help please.

Comment: May be these links can help you out, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms713521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I'd found the Access data type compatibility but it doesn't show how the Access Driver is being wrapped by the .Net DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in your cell would be a byte array. You could just take the length of that.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select data from db", mycon);
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader dr;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
temp = (byte[])dr["data"];
int len = temp.Length;
```